# Realtime notifications in an ASP.NET MVC Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, notifications, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a bunch of notification records stored in a database with a NotificationDateTime field.

I need to be able to display these notifications to the user in real-time as they become available.

I am assuming I am going to have to constantly ping the server from the client every second to check if there are any notifications available at the current time.

I believe the SignalR library would be perfect for this scenario. However, I don't think it is compatible with ASP.NET Core which is what my application is. Are there any alternative techniques that I could use for something like this.

Comment: SignalR `0.2.0-rtm-22752` does support ASP.NET Core 1.1, see http://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server/project.json but you'll most likely need nightly feed as it doesn't seem to be on Nuget, or its delisted on the website https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR

Comment: Once I figure out how to get a nightly feed from a package source would signalR be the ideal thing to use for this scenario?

Comment: Sure, that's what SignalR was made for. But its still in development so not all features of the legacy SignalR client for ASP.NET 4.5 may not be available yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SignalR is kind of available for ASP.NET Core, but it's itself still in development.

The `0.2.0-rtm-22752` version is the latest one build against ASP.NET Core 1.1 (as seen in it's [project.json](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR)).

It's not published on the official nuget feed, so you need to add the `aspnetcore-master` myget feed ([link](https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcore-master)).

Or in VS 2015: 
Tools > Options... > Nuget Package Manager > [+] Icon.

There add "https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-master/api/v3/index.json" as nuget source.

Then the packages of [aspnetcore-master](https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcore-master) become available via nuget.

For SignalR you don't need to poll the server yourself. SignalR will by default try to connect via Websockets and if that fails, fall back to long polling or keep the connection active by other means.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am up and running with SignalR now in my asp.net core web application. I found this small tutorial which has helped me get started: https://radu-matei.github.io/blog/aspnet-core-mvc-signalr/. The tutorial also says to use that NuGet package source. I am now trying to figure out where on the server I need to add my database call to select notifications where NotificationDateTime=DateTime.Now() i.e. _repository.GetNotifications(DateTime.Now()). Would this just be an ActionMethod in my controller that is called by SignalR client?

Comment: You gonna be careful if you use the feed in the post, its the aspnetcore-ci-dev, a nightly build feed which hosts the latest packages, often written against nightly builds of .NET Core/ASP.NET Core and may break often while the packages are upgraded for new changes. Better to use the aspnetcore-master feed, its stable and only milestones get pushed there (i.e. rc1, rc2, rtm, 1.0, 1.1-preview, 1.1 etc)

Comment: got it I switched to using aspnetcore-master. Do you know if I need the AspNetCore.WebSockets package like that tutorial says or no?

Comment: any updates? does anyone know when is the team planning to release SignalR?